# How to extend for loop iteration

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, foreach

I'm looking for a for loop like the below

```
dim i as integer
dim j as integer = 5

For i = 0 To j
   If i = 5 Then
        i = 10
        j = 20
   End If

Next
```

''if i=5 then I want to increment i to 10 and j to 20, so that loop will extend to 10 to 20

can anyone suggest me how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dim i as integer = 1
dim j as integer = 5
while i <= j
    if i = 5 then
       i = 10
       j = 20
    end if
end while
```

I think that with a while youll find it easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to change your loop variables.  The loop is always going to hit 5 and therefore 'extend' to 10.  Just make it loop to 10 in the first place.  If you want to use a changing value of `j` internally, then make a different variable `k` which you change from `5` to `10` at the appropriate time, and use `k` instead.